# Error trying to turn a ByteByffer back into a byteArray when switching endian of Bluetooth UUID

Tags: android, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, bytebuffer

I get a "BufferUnderflowException" when trying to convert a byteArray to a ByteBuffer and then back. Everything seems to go well until I'm about to turn the ByteBuffer back to a byteArray, then I get the exception. According to what I can see the length of the array and the buffer is always the same. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to convert a Bluetooth UUID from big endian to little endian (all the UUID's i get are reversed). The format is standard Bluetooth UUID format, like this: 
"00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"

```
public static String getLittleEndianFromBigEndian(String bigEndianString){
    String littleEndianString = "";
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"getLittleEndianFromBigEndian");
        ArrayList<Integer> dashIndex = new ArrayList<>();
        while (bigEndianString.contains("-")) {
            dashIndex.add(bigEndianString.indexOf("-"));
            bigEndianString = bigEndianString.replaceFirst("-", "");
        }

        int stringLength = bigEndianString.length();
        Log.d(TAG, "bigEndian: " + bigEndianString + ", length: " + stringLength);
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[stringLength / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int hexInt = Integer.parseInt(bigEndianString.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            byteArray[i] = (byte) hexInt;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"byteArray length: " + byteArray.length);
        ByteBuffer convertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArray.length);
        convertBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        convertBuffer.put(byteArray);
        convertBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        convertBuffer.get(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        StringBuffer hexStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            hexStringBuffer.append(Integer.toHexString(byteArray[i]));
            if (dashIndex.contains(byteArray.length - i)) {
                hexStringBuffer.append("-");
            }
        }

        littleEndianString = hexStringBuffer.toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "littleEndian: " + littleEndianString);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return littleEndianString;
}
```

The exception happens on the row "convertBuffer.get(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);"

Here is the stacktrace of the exception:

```
W/System.err: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:123)
    at com.qtatracersystem.ap.Utils.getLittleEndianFromBigEndian(Utils.java:110)
W/System.err:     at com.qtatracersystem.ap.ReadActivity$1.uiAvailableServices(ReadActivity.java:299)
W/System.err:     at com.qtatracersystem.ap.ble.BleWrapper.getSupportedServices(BleWrapper.java:228)
    at com.qtatracersystem.ap.ble.BleWrapper$3.onServicesDiscovered(BleWrapper.java:414)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1$5.run(BluetoothGatt.java:330)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.runOrQueueCallback(BluetoothGatt.java:789)
W/System.err:     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onSearchComplete(BluetoothGatt.java:326)
    at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:110)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
```

Comment: Don't know the issue, but 2 suggestions. 1 use 'ByteBuffer.wrap()', which may avoid the issue. Also, o ce you solve issue, you may be putting the dashes back in wrong place, as you are removing the dashes while reading them, so the index will be wrong. You can do it backwards, which will avoid issue.

Comment: @lionscribe I tried using 'ByteBuffer.wrap()' as you suggested, but then the entire buffer just becomes all zeros, the values disappears. I get a buffer (and because of that a byteArray) like this: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0. Regarding the dashes I actually thought of that and thus I re-insert them backwards instead. There was a mistake in my calculation there however, and thanks to you I noticed it, so Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by just reversing the byteArray manually instead of using a ByteBuffer, but I'll leave this question open so that if someone who knows an answer to this question can actually solve it using the buffer instead. Here is my solution (replaces the rows between

```
Log.d(TAG, "bigEndian: " + bigEndianString + ", length: " + stringLength);
```

and

```
StringBuffer hexStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
```

):

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[stringLength / 2];
        int arrayLength = byteArray.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int hexInt = Integer.parseInt(bigEndianString.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            byteArray[arrayLength-(i+1)] = (byte) hexInt;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"byteArray length: " + arrayLength);


//        ByteBuffer convertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(byteArray.length);
//        convertBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
//        convertBuffer.put(byteArray);
//        convertBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
//        convertBuffer.get(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```